# Joining columns from two tables into one

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have 2 tables, EMPLOYEEAPP and EMPLOYEEINFO.

I want to search to search the EMPLOYEEAPP table for the EMPLOYID when the SECURITYGROUP column is a certain value.

I want to then take the EMPLOYID given from the EMPLOYEEAPP table and search for their corresponding first and last name with the EMPLID column in the EMPLOYEEINFO table.

```
SELECT EMPLOYEEAPP.EMPLOYID, EMPLOYEEINFO.FIRST_NAME, EMPLOYEEINFO.LAST_NAME
FROM EMPLOYEEAPP
WHERE EMPLOYEEAPP.SECURITYGROUP = 'ANALYST'
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEEINFO
ON EMPLOYEEAPP.EMPLOYID=EMPLOYEEINFO.EMPLID
```

I keep receiving the error "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended".

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the `WHERE` clause in the wrong place. The query should be:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEEAPP.EMPLOYID, 
  EMPLOYEEINFO.FIRST_NAME, 
  EMPLOYEEINFO.LAST_NAME
FROM EMPLOYEEAPP
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEEINFO
   ON EMPLOYEEAPP.EMPLOYID=EMPLOYEEINFO.EMPLID
WHERE EMPLOYEEAPP.SECURITYGROUP = 'ANALYST'
```

The order for queries is:

```
SELECT
FROM
JOIN
WHERE 
GROUP BY 
HAVING
ORDER BY
```

Comment: I am now getting "ORA-01722: invalid number", any ideas?

Comment: what is the datatype of `EMPLOYID`, `EMPLID` and `SECURITYGROUP`?

Comment: EMPLOYID: NUMBER; SECURITYGROUP: VARCHAR2(); EMPLID: VARCHAR2()

Comment: @user2100620 You will need to `cast` the columns on the join to the same datatype. Using either `to_char` or `to_number`